# C# Compiler in C?

Tags: c#, .net, c

Is there a way of compiling C# code in C? I can do it in C#, but I'm not sure about how to do it, if you even *can* do it in C. Thanks :)

> Note: Preferably C# (.NET)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are thinking, but you can write a C# Language compiler in C. It would take a while for the later versions, but C# 1.1 wouldn't take forever. If you are looking to implement `System` etc... then yes, that may take near forever.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to just call C# code from C?

Comment: Related posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clr-hosting

Comment: And related article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416471/CLR-Hosting-Customizing-the-CLR

Comment: What's the question? You can't compile *anything* 'in C', but you can compile anything if you have a compiler for it on your platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load CLR into your process (it's a COM component), create the needed objects/interfaces from `Sytem.CodeDOM` namespace and use them. But that's tedious, and I wouldn't recommend it.

Just call `csc.exe` from your program.

Answer (score 2):

No I dont think thats possible unless you are trying to prepare some compilers.

Answer (score 1):

C# code will be executed under `CLR`( Common Language Runtime Engine) hence it is called `ManagedCode`. `CLR` creates proper execution environment for C# code to run properly. C Code is called `UnManaged` Code as it does not run under `CLR`. hence C# code can not be compiled in C.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404385(v=vs.110).aspx — "The hosting API enables unmanaged hosts to integrate the common language runtime (CLR) into their applications".

Comment: Of course. That's how all .NET-produced EXE files work, actually: they start as simple Windows process, then load CLR, initialize it, and tell it to go.